# Power of permutation test for testing whether X,Y are independent- Homework question

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, independence, statistical-power, permutation-test

I'm trying to solve my homework question in the attached Image:I'm stuck on 1.(c).

[image: Question]

Two directions I had in mind were: the central limit theorem, and the Poisson estimation for a large number of experiments in a binomial distribution, but both directions were not successful. In particular, I would like to understand how to incorporate G0 into the equations, although in 1.C the rule of nature is G1...

TIA!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I'm stuck on (a), because it looks false to me. The case where $T$ is a constant provides one counterexample for all $\alpha$, because it *always* rejects $H_0$.